# HTML Editor Action Button

Tags: html, actionfunction, editor

I am looking to create a form within HTML Editor with a `submit button`.

From what I am reading, no functionality is available within HTML Editor.

Can anyone confirm that this is correct?

UPDATES:
Sorry for the lack of details

This is in a lightning community. It is just inline HTML. I have tried the `mailto:` but this funcitonality only pops open an email. What I am looking for is to be able to send an email from this form. Ideally I would hook into JS or APEX from the HTML but these threads tell me otherwise:
- [JavaScript or JQuery function in Html editor of rich text editor](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/80842/javascript-or-jquery-function-in-html-editor-of-rich-text-editor)
- https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=rss_html_editor.htm&type=5
- https://support.salesforce.com/articleView?id=ideas_html_def.htm&type=5

Comment: We're going to need a bit more information than what you just gave us. What are you trying to do? Is this Lightning or Classic? Visualforce or a Lightning Component? Aura or Web Component? What have you tried so far? The more details you can give us, the better. Please [edit] in any additional details.

Comment: @sfdcfox sorry about that, I added more context

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As the docs you linked to show, you cannot use that functionality in an HTML Editor component. You'll want to use a Lightning (Aura or Web) Component for that functionality.

Comment: that's what I figured. I just didn't know if there was a work around so we were able to avoid the custom component and apex class